# How to fill out missing values of df1(at time t) using the ration of df2(t)/df2(t-1) easily?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

There are two dataframes, the first one has some missing values, the second one has no missing values.  The rules are:

1: for `year(t) of df1`, if the value of `year(t)` is missing, using the value of `year(t-1)*ratio`. The `ratio = value of year(t) / value of year(t-1)`  of df2

2: In df1, there is no data in both 2012 and 2013, but we only need to impute missing for 2012, which is one year after the most recent data. We don't have to impute for all the years.

My way is a little stupid. Anyone can have any better ways to fix this?

```
data2 = data.frame('population by age' = seq(5, 8, by = 1), 
                     '2008' = c(145391,
                                140621,
                                136150,
                                131944
                     ),  
                     '2009' = c(148566,
                                143943,
                                139367,
                                135083
                     ), 
                     '2010' = c(152330,
                                147261,
                                142555,
                                138172
                     ),  
                     '2011' = c(156630,
                                151387,
                                146491,
                                141905
                     ),
                     '2012' = c(133545,
                                129737,
                                126124,
                                122678
                      ),
                     '2013' = c(119397,
                                116093,
                                112666,
                                109174)) 


  data1 <- data.frame('grade' = seq(1, 4, by = 1), 
                                     '2008'= c(218701,
                                               NA,
                                               142190,
                                               NA),
                                     '2009' = c(NA,
                                                196398,
                                                155033,
                                                NA),
                                     '2010' = c(212512,
                                                NA,
                                                176268,
                                                143699),
                                     '2011' = c(218529,
                                                198933,
                                                NA,
                                                159103),
                      '2012' = c(NA,
                                 NA,
                                 NA,
                                 NA),
                      '2013' = c(NA,
                                 NA,
                                 NA,
                                 NA)
                      )
```

Comment: Hi Cathy. If you already have a working way, post here as an answer. We can help to refine your code, or it can serve as an inspiration for a better solution. It may not be elegant or optimized, but if do the job, then it's not stupid.

Comment: I am still using for loop

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new data frame with the values to substitute. I'm using package data.table to do it; you can try a solution using dplyr/tidyr if you prefer. Then replace the NAs in data1. Because there's no data for every grade and year, there will still be NAs. So put everything inside a while loop:

```
library(data.table)

while( anyNA(data1[ncol(data1)]) ) {
  data1.sub <- copy(data1)
  for( t in 3:ncol(data1.sub) ) set( data1.sub, j = t, value = data1[[t-1]]*(data2[[t]]/data2[[t-1]]) )
  data1[ is.na(data1) ] <- data1.sub[ is.na(data1) ]
}
```

I'm usin 3:ncol() because there's no information prior to X2008. Here's the result:

```
> data1
  grade  X2008    X2009    X2010    X2011    X2012 X2013
1     1 218701 223476.9 212512.0 218529.0 186321.0 166581.8
2     2     NA 196398.0 200925.1 198933.0 170483.4 152554.2
3     3 142190 155033.0 176268.0 181134.8 155951.2 139310.5
4     4     NA       NA 143699.0 159103.0 137545.8 122405.2
```

The same result will be acomplished using the code in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105933/9817508) if you use for loop to all columns after X2008:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data1)) {
  for (j in 3:ncol(data1)) { 
    if (is.na(data1[i,j])) data1[i,j] = data1[i,j-1]*data2[i,j]/data2[i,j-1]
} }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carlos.  But just like you mentioned, the function 'set' cannot fill out the missing value with grade3, X2012. I am using a for loop to fix this. Feel free to check my code if you are interested. Thanks.

Comment: That's because there's no data in grade3, X2011. You can put the code inside a while loop, so it keep running until all cells in the last column are filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find the column number of the last column with non-na value
  ind <- !is.na(data1)
  t1 <- tapply(data1[ind], col(data1)[ind],tail, 1)
  last_non_na_col <- as.numeric(tail(unlist(dimnames(t1)), n = 1))

  for (i in 1:nrow(data1)) {
    for (j in 3:(last_non_na_col+1)) { 
      if (is.na(data1[i,j])) {
        data1[i,j] = data1[i,j-1]*data2[i,j]/data2[i,j-1]
      }
    }
  }
```

### The output will be like this. And this is exactly what I want.

```
 > data1
    grade  X2008    X2009    X2010    X2011    X2012 X2013
1     1 218701 223476.9 212512.0 218529.0 186321.0    NA
2     2     NA 196398.0 200925.1 198933.0 170483.4    NA
3     3 142190 155033.0 176268.0 181134.8 155951.2    NA
4     4     NA       NA 143699.0 159103.0 137545.8    NA
```

Comment: Works just fine, there's no need of an "easier" way. If it's for your own personal use, then the best code is the one that get the job done and that you can easily read and understand whats going on.